# $\partial_{\mu} \exp[X] = \int_{0}^{1} d \alpha \exp[\alpha X] \partial_{\mu}{X} \exp[(1-\alpha)X]$

Tags: integration, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Suppose $X$ is a matrix, I want to prove
\begin{align}
\partial_{\mu} \exp[X] = \int_{0}^{1} d \alpha \exp[\alpha X] \partial_{\mu}{X}  \exp[(1-\alpha)X]
\end{align}
One naive guess is using the BCH formula and switching the order of $\partial_{\mu} X \exp[(1-\alpha)X]$, but I am not sure how $\alpha$ integrations are done and eventually disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing

$$\exp[X] = \lim_{N\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{X}{N}\right)^N \;\; ,$$

we can express $\partial_{\mu} \exp[X]$ as follows

$$ \partial_{\mu} \exp[X] = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(1+\frac{X}{N}\right)^{k-1}\frac{\partial_{\mu}X}{N}\left(1+\frac{X}{N}\right)^{N-k} \;\; .$$

Note that this has to be further formally justified because I switched the limit and the derivative. I'll leave that aside. Then, rearranging a bit we can write

$$ \partial_{\mu} \exp[X] = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left[\left(1+\frac{X}{N}\right)^N\right]^{\frac{k-1}{N}}\partial_{\mu}X\left[\left(1+\frac{X}{N}\right)^N\right]^{1-\frac{k}{N}}{\frac{1}{N}} \;\; .$$

In the limit, this becomes an integral, $k/N \to \alpha$, $1/N \to d\alpha$. Thus,

\begin{align}
\partial_{\mu} \exp[X] = \int_{0}^{1} d \alpha \exp[\alpha X] \partial_{\mu}{X}  \exp[(1-\alpha)X] \;\; .
\end{align}

You can find a slightly different approach in [Feynman](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/3530/1/FEYpr51.pdf).